# FireBird не видит udf

Tags: firebird

У меня FireBird 3.0 х64 Написал простенькую dll, закинул ее в директорию c Firebird *UDF  (c:\Program Files\Software developments\Firebird_3_0\UDF)*

```
library my;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

function mm: integer; cdecl; export;
begin
  result := 1+1;
end;

exports
  mm;

begin
  isMultiThread:=True;
end.
```

**Отладил на Delphi – работает**
Объявил ее в базе:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION "mm"
RETURNS INTEGER BY VALUE
ENTRY_POINT 'mm' MODULE_NAME 'my';
```

В IBExpert (пытаюсь записать в поле результат функции):

```
update SERVICES_TABLE
set field6 = "mm"()
where DESCRIPTION = 'user manual'
```

ошибка:

> can't format message 13:896 -- message system code -4. invalid request
>   BLR at offset 39. function mm is not defined. module name or
>   entrypoint could not be found.

Уже пытался перенесли udf в другую дерикторию, в  «*firebird.conf*»

> UdfAccess = Restrict D:\MyUDF

***Не помогает***
Все началось из сторонней dll с такой же ошибкой

Что может быть?

**Методом пробы: перенес данную библиотеку на ПК архитектурой х86 и все заработало.

Но БД у меня стоит на х64

Как быть?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать свою UDF с Firebird x64, она должна быть скомпилирована для Windows 64-bit. В Delphi такая возможность появилась начиная с XE2. Также можно воспользоваться бесплатным клоном Lazarus

Comment: Справа в дереве проекта нижняя ветвь "Target Platforms", ПКМ, "Add platform...",